# How does MEF's DirectoryCatalog work?

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, mef, appdomain

`DirectoryCatalog` scans the assemblies in a directory to determine what classes are imported/exported. Any assemblies without an import/export are not loaded.

This is an awesome feature, but how does it work? To investigate the custom attributes on types in an assembly, don't you need to load the Assembly? Once it is loaded, it cannot be unloaded, so that can't be how this works.

Is it doing some sort of AppDomain magic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try it out. `DirectoryCatalog` simply creates an `AssemblyCatalog` for every .dll file in the given directory. Because `AssemblyCatalog` calls `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName`, non-.NET .dll files will not be loaded (an exception is thrown and caught within `AssemblyCatalog`). `AssemblyCatalog` calls `Assembly.Load` on the `AssemblyName` it created. Thus, assemblies are immediately loaded when creating a `DirectoryCatalog`. No magic, no `AppDomains`. But then `MEF` is well known to load assemblies into the current `AppDomain`. Use [MAF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx) if you want assemblies that can be unloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, MAF is fairly obsolete and comes with a significant amount of limitations due to its use of remoting. I haven't identified a good alternative yet. I didn't realize that MEF loads the assemblies, though.

Comment: What do you mean "assemblies that can be unloaded"?

Comment: Allow me to clarify. .NET uses AppDomains to load assemblies.  AppDomains are the most basic "universe" in which assemblies reside and interact with one antoher. E.g. Static variables are only viisible to instances within an AppDomain . Once an assembly is loaded into an AppDomain, you cannot remove the assembly. However, you can unload the complete AppDomain. This is a powerful concept which was first put in practice by ASP.NET. Having said that, implementing a plugin architecture using AppDomains has its challenges.

Answer (score 0):

this is the sample code which can help you.

```
var directoryPath = "Dll folder path";

//Load parts from the available dlls in the specified path using the directory catalog
var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directoryPath, "*.dll");

//Creating an instance of aggregate catalog. It aggregates other catalogs
var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

//Crete the composition container
var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

container.ComposeParts(this);


[ImportMany]
public List<IModule> Modules { get; set; }
```

Comment: How does this help answer my question?

Comment: this is the implementation of directory catalog. how you can use this code to get modules,

Comment: How does that relate to my question?

Comment: Just because it doesn't directly relate to your question doesn't mean it's not useful information

Comment: this response is totally unrelated to question